# Bootstrap 3 notworking with PHP MVC .htaccess

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap style didn't access when i created MVC app. my .htaccess file is that

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png|swf|ttf|eot|svg|woff|GIF)$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

my html coding is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>efrg</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

After I deleted .htaccess file it work correctly. What is the problem with .htaccess file? I properly integrated bootstrap.min.css file too

this is my mvc codes

```
<?php

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$urlParams = explode('/', $url);

if (count($urlParams) === 5) {
    header("location:$url"."users/login");
} else {

    $modelName = $urlParams[4] . 'Model';
    require "./model/$modelName.php";

    $controllerName = $urlParams[4] . 'Controller';
    require "./controller/$controllerName.php";

    $actionName = $urlParams[5] . 'Action';

    $obj = new $controllerName();
    $obj->$actionName();

    include "./view/$urlParams[4]/$urlParams[5].php";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is no working css or js specify

Comment: I did not get you @abhi Ahere

Comment: Your Que is not Clear

Comment: My bootstrap styles are not working.

Comment: As you are using .htaccess every file can be access if your giving absolute path

Comment: Does the last line redirect all request to your index.php file, including js and css?

Comment: yes @ DavidG. But i deleted that line too. it is not working

Comment: there must be path define in your mvc like in config.php.use it.

Comment: which path you've mentioned? @abhi Ahere

Comment: How can i say without looking your mvc.In every mvc there is a path define to access files. these path are absolute path to directory

Comment: I added it @abhi Ahere

Comment: @ abhi Ahere  no no this is MVC app. not an ordinary app. All the redirection happen through index,php file.

Comment: i know , I am also working on mvc and with bootstrap,Thats why i got your problem

Comment: can you post here htaccess file that your is using?

Comment: Do Ctrl+U of your page . All path will appear at top css,jss etc .click on it, if files opens than your path are correct

Comment: Ctrl+U for what? and where?

Comment: At your home page, view page source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one notice that, if header include with the require or include methods some functionalists not working correctly. as i mentioned earlier my bootstrap not worked as it is. i used include instead of header(). that is it. no error.. code is working well